# Image stretches on mobile(only iPhone), but not in browser preview on PC

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on my website at the moment. And I realized, when looking at the mobile site that one of my images stretches/changes it's aspect ratio. Keep in mind this is only on iPhones. I had a few friends look at the site, and only the people with iPhones had the image stretched like this.

**This is the page on the browser**
[image: This is the page on the browser]

**This is the page on my iPhone 11**

[image: This is the page on my iPhone 11]

```
<div class="col d-flex d-md-flex d-xl-flex justify-content-center align-items-md-center">
  <img class="d-xl-flex align-items-xl-center" src="assets/img/headshot.jpg" style="max-width: 90%;">
</div>
```

I originally had height: auto; in there as well, and when trying to solve this issue I found an older post saying that could be the issue. Sadly it did not resolve it.
I know I can easily solve this problem with media queries, but there must be a reason why this happens only on iPhone. I also only have in body styling on this image, you can see it on the browser preview on the inspector.

If you would like to look at it yourself. The Website URL is https://www.robinalexander.at/about-me

Comment: I haven't had time to completely sort it out, but I think the problem is with Safari (rather than just iOS) as you can cause the issue to happen when you make the Safari browser very narrow.  Also, it might get better attention to add the `bootstrap` tag to this question, and to remove the `image-processing` and `ios` ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the classes `d-xl-flex align-items-xl-center` from `img` and give it a `display: block`. The parent `div` will keep the `img` in place